# Write 9 bits binary data in C

Tags: c, binary, bit

I am trying to write to a file binary data that does not fit in 8 bits. From what I understand you can write binary data of any length if you can group it in a predefined length of 8, 16, 32,64.
Is there a way to write just 9 bits to a file? Or two values of 9 bits?

I have one value in the range -+32768 and 3 values in the range +-256. What would be the way to save most space?

Thank you

Comment: post your code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing bits to a file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252697/writing-bits-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: On all systems that you're likely to be working on, files are always a number of bytes in length, i.e. any multiple of 8 bits. You can of course write two 9 bit values (18 bits) using 3 bytes (24 bits).

Comment: There is no code yet, because I don't know how to do it. I want to write values in the range +-255 on 9 bits

Comment: You go up to the next available size. If you're working with integers in the range +-255, use an int16_t (two octets). If you need more than that, go up to an int32_t, and so on.

Comment: You cannot store values in the range –256 to +256 in nine bits either. That is 513 values, and nine bits can only distinguish 512 values.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there's any way using C's file I/O API:s to express storing less than 1 `char` of data, which will typically be 8 bits.

If you're on a 9-bit system, where `CHAR_BIT` really is 9, then it will be trivial.

If what you're really asking is "how can I store a number that has a limited range using the precise number of bits needed", inside a possibly larger file, then that's of course very possible.

This is often called *[bitstreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream)* and is a good way to optimize the space used for some information. Encoding/decoding bitstream formats requires you to keep track of how many bits you have "consumed" of the current input/output byte in the actual file. It's a bit complicated but not very hard.

Basically, you'll need:

- A byte stream `s`, i.e. something you can put bytes into, such as a `FILE *`.
- A bit index `i`, i.e. an unsigned value that keeps track of how many bits you've emitted.
- A current byte `x`, into which bits can be put, each time incrementing `i`. When `i` reaches `CHAR_BIT`, write it to `s` and reset `i` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store values in the range –256 to +256 in nine bits either. That is 513 values, and nine bits can only distinguish 512 values.

If your actual ranges are –32768 to +32767 and –256 to +255, then you can use bit-fields to pack them into a single structure:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a : 16;
    int b :  9;
    int c :  9;
    int d :  9;
};
```

Objects such as this will still be rounded up to a whole number of bytes, so the above will have six bytes on typical systems, since it uses 43 bits total, and the next whole number of eight-bit bytes has 48 bits.

You can either accept this padding of 43 bits to 48 or use more complicated code to concatenate bits further before writing to a file. This requires additional code to assemble bits into sequences of bytes. It is rarely worth the effort, since storage space is currently cheap.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply the principle of base64 (just enlarging your base, not making it smaller).

Every value will be written to two bytes and and combined with the last/next byte by shift and or operations.

I hope this very abstract description helps you.